# JSP to Servlet parameter passing

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a scenario in which there is a jsp, which has couple of hyperlinks. One of the link is coded this way.

```
<a href="Example?op=srk>hyperlink 1</a>
<!--The value srk is replaced dynamically in code-->
```

The above link, would send the request to the servlet named `Example` passing the request parameter through the url. As it's a hyperlink, the request is sent to the `Example` Servlet's doGet() method. In that I am utilizing the request param, processing something and forwarding the request to another jsp further, attaching an attribute(with some object in it) for that request. Functionality works, and I got what I need. But, the side effect or the problem I feel is the URL in the browser has the request parameters visible as shown below.

```
http://localhost:8080/context/Example?op=srk
```

I don't wish to see the parms which are being sent. Firstly, Is my approach reasonable? I mean, Is there any better alternative way to achieve this. I am using the core J2EE(JSP and Servlets), no frameworks, no JavaScript as of now.

Answer (score 1):

I elaborating @Sezin's answer , the best way is to go with the `POST` method to avoid your parameters visible in the url.

As you said your are populating the dynamic value in the `op=srk` variable . you can use a html form to store the variable `op` in the form as hidden variable .

you can use the `submit` button in the form , so that you could handle the request in the `doPost()` of your servlet .

Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

As you click on this link, you're doing an HTTP GET request to your servlet which's why you see the parameters you're passing. You can consider yo use a form or an alternative so you can do an HTTP POST request. After that implementation, this will not be on the address bar.