# Hidden parameters not passed correctly

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl, el

This is in continuation to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26087642/jsp-to-servlet-parameter-passing). I tried to hide parameters in URL using post request. As an attempt here is the approach.

```
<form name="a_form" action="Example" method="post">
      <!--SOME other html code like table etc, here-->
      <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${dataList}" var="thisList">
         <tr>
          <td><c:out value="${thisList.name}"></c:out></td>
          <td>
            <input type="hidden" id="objId" name="objId" value="${thisList.objId}" style="display: none;">
            <input type="submit" name="edit" value="ChangeName"/>
          </td>
        </c:forEach>
      </tbody>
    </form>
```

The above table, initially would display 3 rows with names : {a,b,c} in tabular format. And, the id for each one of the row would be: {1,2,3}, these are hidden and not displayed in the UI. Below is the image that illustrates the UI superficially.

[image]

Note: In the above image assume `ChangeName` is a button.

Each time I click different `ChangeName` button in different row, in the servlet named `Example`, the hidden request parameter value is **always 1**, which is strange. I am not sure where I was wrong. I tried to print the `${thisList.objId}` in one more td, like this

```
 <td><c:out value="${thisList.objId}"></c:out></td><!--This displays 1,2,3 in 3 iterations-->
```

How to get different objId values in the servlet for each different button click in different rows?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, submit to a servlet not another JSP. Second, what you are looking for is:

```
String[] values = request.getParameterValues("objId");
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you are using hidden input  field with the same name "objId". So at the time you submit your form you have only one parameter "objId".

You should create dynamic and different field "Name" to get all the values.